# NameError: name 'createGame' is not defined Not importing

Tags: python

I am doing a project and when I try and use a function from another folder in my project, it has the error `NameError: name 'createGame' is not defined`.

The file that is not being imported properly is the DBFunctions file within the DatabaseFunctions folder.

My main run file:

```
   new(tweet, text)
```

File with the 'new' function in:

```
from DatabaseFunctions.DBFunctions import *
import tweepy    


def new(tweet, text):
    createGame(tweet)
```

The suspect import file:

```
def createGame(tweet):
    if checkUserGame(tweet.user.id) == True:
        executeUpdate()
```

I am so confused because about 10 mins ago it was working, unfortunately I hadn't pushed to git so I don't know what changed it, but it's just weird that I'm getting a NameError

Comment: In what file is `createGame` defined?

Comment: Check the __init__.py file of the `DBFunctions` module, does that module export that function?

Comment: @JohnGordon createGame is defined in the DBFunctions file

Comment: @AvivYaniv I don't have an __init.py file for any of my modules

Comment: First, create an `__init__.py` file under the `DBFunctions` module where you import that function from inside the module, such as `from DatabaseFunctions.DBFunctions.WhereYourFunctionIsImplemented import createGame`. Secondly, in the file you want to use the function, try importing directly the `createGame` by using `from DatabaseFunctions.DBFunctions import createGame`.

Comment: Perhaps this is a circular import issue.  Does the DBFunctions module import the module  where `new()` is defined?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes it does

Comment: Then it is a circular import issue.  The `new()` module (whatever it is called) imports `DBFunctions`, and `DBFunctions` imports the `new()` module.  You can't do that.

Comment: @JohnGordon fixed, you're a legend